# Android 6.0 even with permission 777 chmod cannot read file in data directory

Tags: java, android

I have files which have `chmod 777` permissions in my `data/data/package_directory/here`

I can't read them, like when I want to calculate `crc32` or try to copy the file to SD Card with write external permission in manifest. I am targeting Android Lollipop so run time permissions are not required.

How to fix this? I can not even access files with `777` permission in my directory. I have granted root already to my App?

Error is:

> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Always, whatever I do.

Comment: i think you have to add the permission in manifest for reading file .

Comment: i am reading file from my data directory which already got read/write/execute permission with root ,my app has root already

Answer (score 0):

In your emulator/device you should go to the Settings -> Applications -> (Your app) -> Permissions. Then enable the permissions for memory there

Comment: Hello i have permission storage which is already enabled when i install app in my device because i am using target SDK 21 lollipop so it already grants all permission on api 23

Comment: In my experience including permissions only in the manifest allowed to work on version of android below 6.0 while for marshmallow and higher it required manual setting permissions. Just have a look at your app's permissions in settings, to make sure that at least this problem is eliminated

Comment: see this permission gets already granted when api targeted is below 23 and mine is 21  , screenshot  https://s31.postimg.org/nv2sg90dn/image.png